# Google-Finance: Info-URLs

Tags: google-finance

I know that Google has discontinued their Finance API. However, there still seems to be some kind of API.

For example, these URLs both work:

http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=TTWO
http://www.google.com/finance/getchart?q=TTWO

Is there any documentation of which URLs exist and what their parameters are?

They have added a // to the output and I'm not sure why; however, filtering that out shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: A Google employee has stated that [using this API in an application for public consumption is against their terms of service](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-finance-apis/O8fjsgnamHE/-ZKSjif4yDIJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-finance-apis/oogTGDO2p6E) thread, those URLs were never documented because they weren't intended for public usage. Guess I'll live with what I get from there, at least it's something :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link that worked before: http://code.google.com/apis/finance/developers_guide_protocol.html

I recommend that you try it in http://archive.org/

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the old documentation page with waybackmachine. Unfortunately that didn't give me any informations either :\

Answer (score 0):

Some more bits of URL info here:
http://www.networkerror.org/component/content/44.html?task=view